# Issue with the Kubernetes when using the kubectl commands

Tags: kubernetes

`error: Couldn't get available api versions from server: couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type struct { APIVersion string "json:\"apiVersion,omitempty\""; Kind string "json:\"kind,omitempty\"" }`

Comment: What is your kubectl config?  What's under `~/.kube/config`? Can you share it with sensitive data redacted? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had to set output format to `json`.

```
>kubectl get nodes
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: decoding stdout: couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type struct { APIVersion string "json:\"apiVersion,omitempty\""; Kind string "json:\"kind,omitempty\"" }

>aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]:
AWS Secret Access Key [None]:
Default region name [eu-north-1]:
Default output format [text]: json

>kubectl get nodes
NAME                                            STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
ip-192-168-20-202.eu-north-1.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   370d   v1.21.5-eks-9017834
```

Answer (score 2):

This error can happen in case you have no `~/.kube/config`  in place.
Generating proper config and putting it in its place will resolve the problem.

Please refer to the same topic: [Kubectl on host returns error: couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type struct { APIVersion string "json:"apiVersion,omitempty""; Kind string "json:"kind,omitempty"" #9114](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/9114)

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time this morning troubleshooting this exact error and it looks like this error is thrown when kubeconfig file is not a valid yaml file.

In my particular case the problems with the file were:

- "\n" instead of actual line breaks
- Double-quotes at the begin and end of the file

Config file was auto-generated and fixing both issues allowed kubectl to use it

Answer (score 0):

AWS cli version:

```
aws-cli/2.11.0 Python/3.11.2 Darwin/22.2.0 source/arm64 prompt/off
```

Broke my setup and caused the above error

Kubectl version:

```
GitVersion:"v1.25.4"
```

Gives this error:

```
error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
```

Using aws-cli:

```
aws-cli/2.4.18 Python/3.8.8 Darwin/22.2.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
```

Kubectl version:

```
GitVersion:"v1.22.5"
```

Fixed the issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, adding an answer for those who are using Terraform and didn't see a solution with upgrading awscli and such. I had to update the command in one of my Terraform providers to include a --output json on the aws eks get-config command:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
    command     = "aws"
    args        = [
      "eks",
      "get-token",
      "--output",
      "json",
      "--cluster-name",
      data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.name
    ]
  }
}
```

Note this command is getting a token from the aws cli, but if you your output format is 'text' or not set for some reason, you can get this error because the provider is expecting JSON and getting a text string. Adding the "--output", "json" fixed it in my case.